# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with fetchCallback

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm having this issue when I run my app

***Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component***

But I dont have a direct call to an api, instead I did something like this:

```
  const fetchCallback = useCallback(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      let response = await getSomething(
        someParam
      );
      
      setSomething(response?.item)
      setLoading(false);
    };
        // eslint-disable-next-line
      }, [someParam]);

        useEffect(() => {
        fetchCallback();
       }, [fetchCallback]);
```

Do I still need to add a local variable to set when the component is mounted and unmounted?

Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isMounted = true;              
    if (isMounted) fetchCallback();
  return () => { isMounted = false }; 
}, []);
```

Is this ok o no need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just calling `fetchCallback` just as `useEffect(() => { fetchCallBack() }, [fetchCallback])`, you should be guaranteed that it's called on initial mount and not again, so in particular the component *will* be mounted.

More generally, as long as the `fetchCallback` code doesn't do anything that relies on the component being mounted, you shouldn't need to keep track of an `isMounted` state variable.  In particular, it's fine to call `setState` functions even when the component isn't mounted.  You just shouldn't assume that refs set via `<... ref={ref} ...>` are defined, because that will only be true when the component is mounted.